# Filtering search result with Mpdreamz/NEST

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index which contains news from various Sources like economictimes,cnn etc.I am using Mpdreamz/NEST for integrating elasticsearch in C#. Is there any way to display a field named 'Content' from index which contains the word 'Accounts' respective  of the souces provided.looking for something like
    getContent(keyword="Accounts",source={List}){
    }

Comment: Hey author of NEST here i would like to answer your question but i'm not sure what you mean exactly. Could you update your question with a bit more information on what it is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MartijnLaarman I mean to pass array of string to a search field to match records.I got its working... I am using dynamic search would like to use mapping class instead.Can you help me to map my index https://gist.github.com/3606852

Comment: @MartijnLaarman var result1 = client.Search(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10).Filter(ff => ff.
Term("Categories.Types.Events.NumberEvent.event", "Notable")   
)
.FacetTerm(q => q.OnField("Categories.Types.Events.NumberEvent.event"))
);this returned  0 result for index https://gist.github.com/3689216  please help me out